# How do I select dropdown checkboxes in html with c# and webkit (javascript)?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, webkit

I'm working with the WebKitBrowser in C# (Visual Studio 2010) and I want to automatically create a user in the web application of owncloud.
The login form is displayed in [Picture 1](http://imageshack.us/a/img802/6515/e29.png). By clicking "Gruppen" a dropdown field with checkboxes appears ([Picture 2](http://imageshack.us/a/img203/1203/2svs.png)). The html-code is below:

```
<form id="newuser" autocomplete="off">
<input id="newusername" type="text" placeholder="Loginname" /> 
<input type="password" id="newuserpassword" placeholder="Passwort" /> 
<select class="groupsselect" id="newusergroups" data-placeholder="groups" title="Gruppen" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Benutzer">Benutzer</option>
    <option value="admin">admin</option>
</select> 
<input type="submit" value="Anlegen" />
</form>
```

I'm **able to fill** the **newusername** and **newuserpassword** textboxes and **submit** the form, for example:

```
String javascript = "document.getElementById('newusername').value = '" + newusername + "';";
WebKitBrowser1.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(javascript);
```

But I'm **not able** to select a value in **newusergroups** (Picture 2), for example:

```
String javascript = "document.getElementById('newusergroups').options[1].selected = true;";
String javascript = "document.getElementById('newusergroups').value = 'admin';";
```

Maybe someone can help me? Thanks in advance and best regards,

Oli

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the value for the select element, by selecting an option you have already set the 'value'. So remove this line...

```
String javascript = "document.getElementById('newusergroups').value = 'admin';"
```

If the following line is not working

```
String javascript = "document.getElementById('newusergroups').options[1].selected = true;";
```

You may wish to try this instead...

```
String javascript = "document.getElementById('newusergroups').selectedIndex = 1;";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it does not work. Everything i tried with "selected", "checked", "value", "selectedIndex" does not work.

Comment: Is there any other way? Like manipulating the html-code and setting an option to selected="selected"?

Comment: Does anything change if you drop the ; ? For instance: String javascript = "document.getElementById('newusergroups').selectedIndex = 1";

Comment: Might be worth reading this related post: http://iphonedevsdk.vanillaforums.com/discussion/comment/96803 - seems here the issue is the element is not yet "ready" on the page. I.e. the javascript is being ran before the element has been added.

Comment: dropping the ; doesn't change anything. I tried document.getElementById('newusergroups').focus(); and after that document.getElementById('newusergroups').selectedIndex = 1; But that doesn't select the element. I call the javascript in WebKitBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) and I tried executing the javascript manually after the page has loaded with no change...

Comment: maybe there is a function (class="groupsselect") that must be called? elements in an following table have the attribute selected="selected" when they are properly checked. when i manually (mouse-click) check one element, the title "Gruppen" changes to the name of the checkbox

Comment: I'm out of ideas, the javascript code you've written fits the DOM manipulation you're trying to achieve. Must be something about the browser or framework you're using?

Comment: I'm using the webkitbrowser and .net framework 3.5. but why does manipulating the textboxes work and not selecting an checkbox? is there any way to simulate a click on the checkbox?